# Edit link and content overlapping

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page

The external link icon and the CV link text is overlapping on the ["Edit Profile & Settings Page"](https://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/current).  This also occurs for the Privileges link.

> [image]

Reproduced on:

- FF42.0 Ubuntu, SO Rev - 3118
- Chrome 47 - Windows 7
- Chrome 46 - Arch Linux

Comment: Can reproduce this particular bug (and was on my way here to report it!).  While we're at it, the Privileges link suffers from the same affliction.  Perhaps the two are related.

Comment: So @Makoto the jobs tag isn't suitable here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry about that. Issue here seems to stem from not nesting the menu `<ul>`'s correctly. They were sitting outside the `<li>` elements instead of within them. This has been corrected and is being built out into production.